# How do I use smart pointer to point at sibling class objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, smart-pointers

I am a little confused with new smart pointers. I want to use one pointer to point at two different objects of sibling classes (same parent).

so basically I have a parent class `Parent` and two child classes `Child1` and `Child2`

```
class Parent{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Parent{
    void foo(){
        //something
    }

}

class Child2 : public Parent{
    void foo(){
        //something different
    }

}
```

The pointer *say* `ptr` is first pointing at `Child1` and then it should point at `Child2`
Doing so I want to use the same pointer to behave differently as per the implementations inside those sibling classes.

I think,
`Parent ptr = new Child1()` a non smart pointers way, should work in this case if I do `(Child2 *)ptr`

But I am sure there would be a better way through smart pointers.

I know that **reinterpret_ptr** does have some usecase around this topic but i couldn't understand the explanation on gfg. ALSO my main Question is How do I declare this pointer?

`unique_ptr<Parent> ptr = make_unique<Child1>();`?

Comment: `I think,
Parent ptr = new Child1() a non smart pointers way, should work in this case if I do (Child2 *)ptr` No it won't. `ptr` points to a `Child1`. There __is no `Child2`__. Don't cast it to one.

Comment: Your "non smart pointer way" is undefined behavior.

Comment: You cannot have a pointer to `Child1` and pretend it's a pointer to `Child2`. Whatever casts you use, it's still wrong.

Comment: *"The pointer say `ptr` is first pointing at `Child1` and then it should point at `Child2`"* -- this is not phrased correctly for how pointers work. Pointers point to objects, not classes. So you could say that `ptr` first points to **an object of type** `Child1`, and then it should point to **an object of type** `Child2` (which is necessarily a different object with just what's in the question).

Comment: Casts are not a magic way to convert one object type into another. How would the compiler know how to do that? Casts are basically just a way of saying to the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing and if you interpret this *foo* as a *bar* it'll be fine", but it's on you to then make sure that the cast actually makes sense and if it doesn't, then you have [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) on your hands. Casts are *rarely* the correct solution - sure, cases exist where casts make sense - they are few and far between and you really should be a C++ expert before using them.

Comment: Thanks all, for the corrective comments. Yes the question was phrased poorly. I get the point and might have to think some different way to solve the problem rather than casting . maybe!

Answer (score 3):

`Parent ptr = new Child1()` will not compile, since `ptr` is not declared as a pointer.  You need to add a `*` to it, eg:

```
Parent *ptr = new Child1();
```

Now then, `(Child2 *)ptr` is *undefined behavior*, because a `Child1` object is not a valid `Child2` object and vice versa, so you can't just type-cast the pointer.  You need to point at a whole separate `Child2` object, eg:

```
Parent *ptr = new Child1();
...
delete ptr;
ptr = new Child2();
...
delete ptr;
```

Don't forget to add a `virtual` destructor to `Parent`!

Now, you can do the same thing with smart pointers, eg:

```
unique_ptr<Parent> ptr = make_unique<Child1>();
...
ptr = make_unique<Child2>();
```